# Setting a shipment method and payment method programatically in magento

Tags: magento

i am trying to enable shipping method, update the shipping costs and enable payment methods based on a condition through an observer. I was able to add a field to the checkout page to check for the condition but i am not sure how do i enable/disable shipping methods and payment methods and update the shipping costs? Could some one provide a code snippet to perform this or point me in the right direction? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the shipping and payment methods isAvailable() or isActive() methods to meet your conditions and show the availability or change the price of shipping method. If you need to add a payment method fee then you need to implement a total object for a payment method.

However in checkout/onepage the process is address > shipping > payment and if you change your conditions on last step then you ideally need a user confirmation to change the choices he has made in previous steps.